# Jquery Accordion plugin fails to reinitialize after a destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ This plugin is used to create an accordion. The contents of the accordion need to be updated dynamically, thus I do a

```
obj.accordion('destroy')
// update the contents here...
obj.accordion()  // recreating it
```

This results in panels that have been newly added to work normally, but panels (h3 + content) that were there previously to act as if 2 clicks happen insted of 1 (opening closing rapidly)

Behaviour is reproducible in Chrome and not in Firefox.

Help is appreciated as to detect the issue.

Comment: try `('create')` instead of `()` for reinitialization.

Comment: negative: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'create'